# How do I tell this jquery not to fire on mobile or tablets

Tags: jquery

I have this bit of jquery that I only want it to trigger for larger screens and avoid mobile and tablet, but how?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

//GET BROWSER WINDOW HEIGHT
var currHeight = $(window).height();
//SET HEIGHT OF SIDEBAR AND CONTENT ELEMENTS
$('.fixed-col').css('height', currHeight);

//ON RESIZE OF WINDOW
$(window).resize(function() {

    //GET NEW HEIGHT
    var currHeight = $(window).height();    
    //RESIZE BOTH ELEMENTS TO NEW HEIGHT
    $('.fixed-col').css('height', currHeight);
});

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/tREsr/

Comment: That depends on *why* you want to avoid smartphones and tablets. Is it their small size? Tablets can be 1024px wide or wider. Is it their touchscreens? Surface Pro might have both a touchscreen and a mouse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fiddle has multiple syntax errors, plus jQuery was never loaded.

Perhaps this it what you meant to do:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(window).width() >= 400) {
        $(window).resize(function () {
            var currHeight = $(window).height();
            $('.fixed-col').css('height', currHeight);
        }).trigger('resize'); // run it once right away
    };
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/UXQCL/

Answer (score 2):

Using [`matchMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.matchMedia) will allow you to define media queries in your JS:

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  /* the view port is at least 400 pixels wide */
} else {
  /* the view port is less than 400 pixels wide */
}
```

If you need to support older browsers there is a polyfill included in [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/download/#-mq-teststyles), or you can grab the [standalone version](https://github.com/paulirish/matchMedia.js/)

Comment: Which wouldn't apply to many tablets, sadly. In any event, if you're using jQuery anyway it's easier to just test whether `$(window).width() >= 400`

Comment: The facts tell a different story - http://caniuse.com/#search=matchmedia Seems well supported to me. I even pointed out the polyfill for older browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
 // some code..
}
```

You can check here

Comment: While this will probably work *for now*, testing the User-Agent string to detect browsers is notoriously error-prone and non-future-proof: what if BlackBerry make a laptop? Or somebody makes a browser called "webOStuff!"? This is the reason why modern browsers have User-Agent strings stuffed with keywords to trigger detectors primed for their predecessors and competitors.